# SystemVerilog assertion

Tags: system-verilog, assertions, system-verilog-assertions

I have the following interfaces:

```
interface tx_in_interface (input bit clk, input bit tx_srstn);
   //dut input
   logic [15:0] xi;   
   logic [15:0] xq;   
   logic [15:0] sin;  
   logic [15:0] cos;  
   int  chind2;   
endinterface



interface tx_out_interface (input bit clk, input bit tx_srstn);
   //dut output
   logic [15:0] y;
   int chind2;   
endinterface
```

I want to check that every time sin equal to 1(dec) y will be `xi/sqrt(2)`, and every time cos equal to 1(dec) y will be `xq/sqrt(2)`.

Can I do it with a specific kind of systemVerilog assertion (with no use of scoreboard or coverage)?

Comment: Yes. Two SVA assertions would do the trick, one to check that `y` is `xi/sqrt(2)` when `sin` is 1,the other to check that `y` is `xq/sqrt(2)` when `cos` is 1. It is not clear what you are asking. Do you know about SVA assertions?

Comment: @Matthew Taylor - I know, but new in this issue (SVA assertions). Can you give code example for one of the case?

Comment: Here's a [SystemVerilog Assertions Tutorial](http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/tutorial/assertions/) on [my company's website](http://www.doulos.com).

Comment: @Matthew Taylor -  I have already started to read it. The problem that I have not seen yet asssertion which involve signals from different interfaces.

Comment: You can use hierarchical references just like you would anywhere else in Verilog/SystemVerilog, eg `assert property (...module_inst.tx_in_interface.inst.sin == 16'd1 -> ...module_inst.tx_out_interface.inst.y == ...module_inst.tx_in_interface.inst.xi/sqrt(2)) ...`

Comment: @Matthew Taylor - where I wtite it? in the top testbench?

Comment: @Matthew Taylor - Is there anyway to write it inside the first interface?

Comment: You can write it where you like. Use hierarchical naming to access anything that is not in scope.

Comment: @Matthew Taylor - can I use hierarchical naming in interfaces?

Comment: Yes, you can use hierarchical naming in interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think you can simple write the following 2 properties.

```
property sin_check;
  (sin == 'd1) |-> y == (xi/sqrt(2));
endproperty

property cos_check;
  (cos == 'd1) |-> y == (xq/sqrt(2));
endproperty
```

Answer (score 0):

Following 2 assertions can verify your specified condition:

```
//Creating instances of interface 
tx_in_interface tx_i; 
tx_out_interface tx_o;

//Checking conditions 
assert property (@posedge tx_i.clk) (tx_i.sin == 1) |-> tx_o.y == (tx_i.xi/sqrt(2)); 
else $error("Sine output error!");

assert property (@posedge tx_o.clk) (tx_i.cos == 1) |-> tx_o.y == (xq/sqrt(2)); 
else $error("Cos output error!");
```

[SystemVerilog Assertions Tutorial](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/tutorial/assertions/) by Duolos is an excellent resource.